# Finding an image (Linear Transformations) $T(2,-1,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

> Let $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(1,1,1) = (2,0,-1), T(0,-1,2) = (-3,2,-1)$ and $T(1,0,1)=(1,1,0)$.  Find the indicated image $T(2,-1,1)$

I used the rule that:

> If $v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n$, then $T(v) = T(c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...+c_nv_n) = c_1T(v_1)+c_2T(v_2)+...+c_nT(v_n)$

So I did the following:

$T(2,-1,1) = 2(2,0,-1)-(-3,2,-1)+(1,1,0)=(8,-1,0)$

The book has this as the answer:

> Because $(2,-1,1)$ can be written as
>
> $(2,-1,1) = -\frac{3}{2}(1,1,1)-\frac{1}{2}(0,-1,2)+\frac{7}{2}(1,0,1)$, then
>
> $T(2,-1,1)=-\frac{3}{2}T(1,1,1)-\frac{1}{2}T(0,-1,2)+\frac{7}{2}T(1,0,1)$

which gives a final answer of:

$\left(2,\frac{5}{2},2\right)$

Where did the fractions come from and why is my answer different if I'm using the same rule?

Comment: You are confusing the decomposition along the elements given by the problem with the decomposition along the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: $(2,-1,1) \not = 2(1,1,1)-(0,-1,2)+(1,0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the vector $$\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ as a combination of the vectors $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
not as a combination of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is what you did. (That's because you don't immediately know how $T$ acts on the standard basis, but you *do* know how $T$ acts on the three vectors listed above: that's exactly what you're given.)